# Selecting least common item from an enum

Tags: c#, linq

A little background information: I am currently making a website on which people can make reservations for a restaurant. When making a reservation, people can select an hour when they want to come and eat. They don't choose a specific time, but they choose a "general" timestamp from a dropdown menu (e.g. 11h - 12h, 13h - 14h, 17h - 18h, etc).

When submitting the reservation, the system needs to give the customer a more specific time. This is done to spread customers a bit, so we can avoid big spikes in customers. The "more specific time" is the hour plus either 0, 15, 30 or 45 minutes (I did this with a Minutes-enumeration).

I made a "TimeStamp" class which contains an Hours and Minutes enum.
The "Reservation" class contains some info about the reservation, and a Timestamp.

Now, when making a new reservation, I need to find the most optimal "minutes" value. This is the value with the least amount of reservations (within the chosen hour).

This is the code I have written so far, but it's not working:

```
var reservationsInTheSameHour = context.Reservations
                                    .Where(r => r.TimeStamp.Hour == model.Uur);
var bestMinuteChoice = reservationsInTheSameHour
                           .GroupBy(r => r.TimeStamp.Minute)
                           .OrderByDescending(m => m.Count())
                           .Select(rr => rr.Key);
```

The reason I think this is not working, is because some minutes have not been chosen yet, so they won't be selected.

Does anyone think of a more efficient way of doing this, or can help me out with this LINQ?

EDIT:

This was the Hours- and Minutes-enum:

```
    public enum Minutes
    {
        _00,
        _15,
        _30,
        _45
    }

    public enum Hours
    {
        [Display(Name = "Tussen 11u en 12u")]
        _11u,

        [Display(Name = "Tussen 12u en 13u")]
        _12u,

        [Display(Name = "Tussen 13u en 14u")]
        _13u,

        [Display(Name = "Tussen 17u en 18u")]
        _17u,

        [Display(Name = "Tussen 18u en 19u")]
        _18u,

        [Display(Name = "Tussen 19u en 20u")]
        _19u,

        [Display(Name = "Tussen 20u en 21u")]
        _20u,

        [Display(Name = "Tussen 21u en 22u")]
        _21u
    }
```

I managed to solve the issue myself, by using a Dictionary containing the enum-values along with how many times the Minutes-value existed within the Reservations.

```
var reservationsInTheSameHour = context.Reservations.Where(r => r.TimeStamp.Hour == model.Uur);
var minuteCounts = Enum.GetValues(typeof (TimeStamp.Minutes))
                       .Cast<TimeStamp.Minutes>()
                        .ToDictionary(
                                minute => minute,
                                minute => reservationsInTheSameHour.Count(r => r.TimeStamp.Minute == minute)
                         );
var bestMinute = minuteCounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == minuteCounts.Min(aa => aa.Value)).Key;
reservation.TimeStamp = new TimeStamp(model.Uur, bestMinute);
```

aush's solution is much more elegant. This is what I ended up with:

```
private static TimeStamp.Minutes GetOptimalMinute(IQueryable<Reservation> reservations, TimeStamp.Hours hour)
{
    foreach (TimeStamp.Minutes enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeof (TimeStamp.Minutes))
        .Cast<TimeStamp.Minutes>()
        .Where(enumVal => reservations.All(r => r.TimeStamp.Minute != enumVal)))
    {
        return enumVal;
    }


    return reservations.Where(r => r.TimeStamp.Hour == hour)
        .GroupBy(r => r.TimeStamp.Minute)
        .OrderBy(m => m.Count())
        .Select(rr => rr.Key).First();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your input data?

Comment: can you post the code for minutes enumeration?

Comment: What exactly is not working? The first time you run through that code? Perhaps you need to treat the case where `reservationsInTheSameHour` is empty and just assign `0` to `bestMinuteChoice` directly.

Comment: Wouldn't the best choice be the one with the fewest reservations already, so OrderBy rather than OrderByDescending would have been my expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your problem is that you are looking for the least common between ones presented. So, you can just first check if you have enumeration values that are not present:

```
foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(Minute))
{
    if (reservations.All(r => r.Minute != enumVal))
    {
        return enumVal;
    }
}

return reservations.Where(r => r.Hour == Hour.eleven)
                   .GroupBy(r => r.Minute)
                   .OrderBy(m => m.Count())
                   .Select(rr => rr.Key)
                   .Last();
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I managed to solve my issue myself by using a dictionary that contains the counts, but your solution is much more elegant.

Comment: @Mavamaarten, assuming the `reservations` collection contains 10.000 items and you suddenly change the `Minute` enum to have 12 members (each 5 min), this solution looks not so elegant anymore, because you might get a performance drop. The `foreach` loop should be optimized.

Comment: @dymanoid I agree, but I don't think this will be an issue in this particular use case. This webapp will only be used for a one-time event, and I'm not expecting more than 100 reservations in total.